# Gensim Doc2Vec - Pass corpus sentences to Doc2Vec function

Tags: python, text-mining, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I used the `MySentences` class for extracting sentences from all files in a directory and use this sentences for train a *word2vec* model.
My dataset is unlabeled.

```
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                yield line.split()

sentences = MySentences('sentences')
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences)
```

Now I want to use that class to make a *doc2vec* model. I read [Doc2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) reference page. `Doc2Vec()` function gets sentences as parameter, but it doesn't accept above sentences variable and return error :

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'words'
```

What is the problem? What is the correct type of that parameter?

**Update :**

I think, unlabeled data is the problem. It seems doc2vec needs labeled data.

Comment: Above code runs find for me! python 2.7 and gensim 0.12

Comment: You are right. I want to use that class to make a doc2vec model.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use extra classes to solve the problem. In new updates of library, a new function `TaggedLineDocument` added to transform sentence to vector.

```
sentences = TaggedLineDocument(INPUT_FILE)
```

and then, train the model

```
model = Doc2Vec(alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.025)
model.build_vocab(sentences)

for epoch in range(10):
    model.train(sentences)
    model.alpha -= 0.002
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha
    print epoch
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike word2vec, doc2vec needs every train entry to be labeled with an unique id.
This is needed because later when it predicts similarities its result will be doc ids (unique ids of the train entries), like words are the predictions for word2vec.

Here is a piece of my code that does the exact thing you want to achieve

```
 class DynamicCorpus(object):
 def __iter__(self):
     with open(csf_file) as fp:
         for line in fp:
             splt = line.split(':')
             text = splt[2].replace('\n', '')
             id = splt[0]
             yield TaggedDocument(text.split(), [id])
```

my csv file has format
id:text

later you can just feed the corpus to the model

```
coprus = DynamicCorpus()

d2v = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(min_count=15,
                      window=10,
                      vector_size=300,
                      workers=15,
                      alpha=0.025,
                      min_alpha=0.00025,
                      dm=1)
d2v.build_vocab(corpus)

for epoch in range(training_iterations):
    d2v.train(corpus, total_examples=d2v.corpus_count, epochs=d2v.iter)
    d2v.alpha -= 0.0002
    d2v.min_alpha = d2v.alpha
```